# TWIG - Divide into columns with item class

Tags: twig

I use TIWG and Wordpress.

I'm trying to create a system for a menu to generate new column when an item get a class.

When a menu item get specific class (`.split`). I would like to create a new column.

### For example, I got :

```
<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
    <li class="menu__item split"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
    <li class="menu__item split"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>
```

When an item get class `.split`, I would like to create a new `.menu__list`

### Like that :

```
<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item split"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item split"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>
```

### I wrote that, but I got an issue :

```
{% for item in menu_main.get_items %}
    <ul class="nav__col">
        <li class="menu__item">{{ item.title }}</li>
    {% if item.classes[0] == 'split'  %}
    </ul><ul class="menu__list">
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

### I got an output with an empty `ul` :

```
<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item split"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__list">

</ul>

<ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
    <li class="menu__item"></li>
</ul>
```

### I tried to use a variable to get this condition once, without success

```
{% set break = false %}
{% for item in menu_main.get_items %}
    <ul class="menu__list">
        <li class="menu__item">{{ item.title }}</li>
    {% if item.classes[0] == 'split' and not break  %}
    {% set break = true %}
    </ul><ul class="menu__list">
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Can I have some help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop, you have an outer `<ul>`. This then creates an `ul` for every menu item.

Without seeing what `menu_main.get_items` returns, this is my best guess:

```html
{# only create one outer list #}
<ul class="menu__list">
  {% for item in menu_main.get_items %}
    {% if item.classes[0] is defined and item.classes[0] is same as('split') %}
      {# the duplication here is intended to add the split class,
         this could be more *dry* but this way it's easier to read #}
      <li class="menu__item split">{{ item.title }}</li>

      {# close and reopen #}
      </ul><ul class="menu__list">
    {% else %}
      <li class="menu__item">{{ item.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Demo: https://twigfiddle.com/zhm9bh